# Package fncychap: how do you make the title boxes smaller

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, fncychap

I'm new to LaTeX and wanted to write my dissertation in report mode.

I am trying to use the package `fncychap`but I noticed that my typeset version has a massive box that stretches to halfway down the page. (I removed the word "Chapter" and have made a few other formatting changes.)

This is the code that I'm using:

```
%set document class
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%% CHAPTER FORMATTING %%
\usepackage{fix-cm} 
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\ChNameVar{\Huge}\ChNumVar{\fontsize{62}{65}}
\ChTitleVar{\centering\Huge} \ChRuleWidth{1pt}
\renewcommand\FmN[1]{}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to make the box smaller, like in the original [documentation](http://www.nagel-net.de/Latex/DOKU/fncychap.pdf)?

Thanks,

Jenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few minor changes to your code and now the result should be closer to what you wanted to achieve (the box is tighter now). I also made comments to explain the changes a bit.

```
%set document class
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%% CHAPTER FORMATTING %%
\usepackage{fix-cm} 
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
% not needed
%\ChNameVar{\Huge}
% without \selectfont to actually activate the changes \fontsize doesn't do
% anything
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{62}{65}\selectfont}
% this is pretty close to the default being \centering\Huge\rm, so not needed
%\ChTitleVar{\centering\Huge}
% this is the default anyway
%\ChRuleWidth{1pt}
\renewcommand\FmN[1]{}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

Output of the first page:

[image]